# How to parse UUID from method param for Spring Security @PreAuthorize using SpEL?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-el

i have this controller with Spring @PreAuthorize annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and #id == authentication.name")
public ResponseEntity<UserProfileDTO> updateProfile(@PathVariable(name = "id") final UUID id) {
//service call
}
```

but the problem is, that principal is String, and equals return false.
How i can call java.util.UUID.fromString(authentication.name) ?

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and #id == T(java.util.UUID).fromString(authentication.name)")
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Also you could do some more research (first link on Google with  `spring el method call` on SO), before asking a question, which is already answered.